# Stored Procedures Creation Details

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently documenting a database and I am now working on stored procedures.

I would like to know if there is any way to know who created which stored procedure and when they created it?

I am working on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**When** a stored procedure was created is found in `sys.procedures`:

```
USE (your database here)
GO 

SELECT name, create_date FROM sys.procedures
```

**Who** created it is not recorded by SQL Server, as far as I know.

You would have to setup your own tracking system, e.g. by using [SQL Server DDL triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to capture when stored procedure are being created. Unless you have such a custom tracking system in place already, there's no way to find out who created a stored procedure 5 years ago ....

Comment: i have tried querying this on my db but it returns zero records. if the creator isn't recorded, is there any other way perhaps like a Third Party Tool out there that can help me with this? Thank you!!!

Comment: @SmileyFace: you need to be **in the relevant database** when you run this query, to get any results.

Comment: Or use `database_name.sys.procedures`.

Comment: +1 to capture *who* created a stored procedure, you'd need a [DDL trigger](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) or auditing or a trace of some kind running.

Comment: @SmileyFace: as for the creator of the database - I doubt this is available anywhere - so no third-party tool will help. You'd have to setup some logging yourself (by e.g. capturing DDL triggers that create stored procedures)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes but prior to today, we do not have those DDL Triggers. So is there any way for us to track the trail of the existing procedures?

Comment: @SmileyFace: no, unless you have some custom logging in place, there is no way to find this information - it's just plain not recorded anywhere......

Comment: @SmileyFace nope. Use this as a learning experience: if you don't trust your users, either don't give them carte blanche rights to create whatever they want, or audit them (and don't give them rights to mess with the audit).

Comment: @SmileyFace this might also be a good time to consider source control and a release policy instead of cowboy-style, everyone-can-update-in-production.